# How to implement the sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

I would like to implement [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm. The pseudocode as provided in the preceding link is

```
Input: an integer n > 1

Let A be an array of Boolean values, indexed by integers 2 to n,
initially all set to true.

for i = 2, 3, 4, ..., not exceeding √n:
  if A[i] is true:
    for j = i^2, i^2+i, i^2+2i, i^2+3i, ..., not exceeding n :
      A[j] := false

Output: all i such that A[i] is true.
```

The first problem is dealing with indices. What I've done simply is to match the index with the location of data for the sake of simplicity. My following figure depicts this issue.

[image]

My code is not generating prime numbers according to the aforementioned algorithm. This is my implementation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>


int main()
{
    int n(30);
    std::vector<bool> A;

    for( int i(2); i <= n+2; ++i )
        A.push_back(true);

    for ( int i(2); i <= sqrt(n); ++i ){
        if ( A[i] == true ){
            int a(0);
            for (  int j(i*i); j <= n; j += a*i ){
                A[j] = false;
                ++a;
            }
        }
    }
    for ( int i(2); i < A.size(); ++i ){
        if ( A[i] == true )
            std::cout << i  << " ";
    } 
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The result is

```
2 3 5 7 8 11 13 14 15 17 19 20 21 22 23 26 28 29
```

Why my code doesn't yield the right answer? Any hints?

Comment: In the inner-most loop in the algo, the step is constant. Your inner-most loop has an increasing step.

Comment: @Mat, why it is constant? According to this line `i^2, i^2+i, i^2+2i, i^2+3i`, `i` is multiplied by an increasing variable.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`). **Use the debugger** (`gdb`) to run your program step by step and query the program state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in this loop:

```
        for (  int j(i*i); j <= n; j += a*i ){
            A[j] = false;
            ++a;
        }
```

You should either increment `j` by `i` with no `a` multiplier:

```
        for (  int j(i*i); j <= n; j += i ){
            A[j] = false;
        }
```

or calculate a brand new value for `j` with incrementing `a`:

```
        for (  int a(0), j(i*i); j <= n; j = i*i + ++a*i ){
            A[j] = false;
        }
```

but not mix the two approaches.

Answer (score 2):

The inner for-loop is making too large steps. The correct solution is to make the step `j += i`, the variable `a` is not needed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    int n(30);
    std::vector<bool> A;

    for( int i(2); i <= n+2; ++i )
        A.push_back(true);

    for ( int i(2); i <= sqrt(n); ++i ){
        if ( A[i] == true ){
            for (  int j(i*i); j <= n; j += i ){
                A[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    for ( int i(2); i < A.size(); ++i ){
        if ( A[i] == true )
            std::cout << i  << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8dbf01dccb1034fb)